# Prestashop background load as questionmarks

Tags: php, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Hello i am currently developing a prestashop store but for some reason the background of the store loads as question marks, the store in question is http://www.exotique.bg/ i checked paths, files and everything is ok but still can't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Prestashot` shows question mark if it can't find image in given address.

Your backgroud address is:

> http://www.exotique.bg/img/fon4.jpg

but need to be:

> http://www.exotique.bg/themes/simpleresponsivetheme/img/fon4.jpg

Relace line:

```
body {
    background: url("/img/fon4.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

with:

```
body {
    background: url("../img/fon4.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It will try to find image in one level up, not in root.

Comment: Indeed this was the problem however i tried your solution earlier is just that the damn cache was activated and it didn't show (memo to self alwats check if cache is active before making changes) ^^, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

edit your global.css , question mark background image came from `body {background: url("/img/fon4.jpg") repeat;}` replace with your desired image or just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your website,,this is because of your CSS Rules,

```
body {
background: url("/img/fon4.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

you have two general options to resolve this,you can replace the 125*125 "fon4.jpg" with another file,that will replace your current background,

or you can change the "[global.css](http://www.exotique.bg/themes/simpleresponsivetheme/css/global.css)" file on the line 16 and refer to another background
 you can do which you prefer

for changing a template and creating a template you must know CSS,

I recommend you to take a look at [Lynda.com](http://lynda.com) website and go to CSS section and learn how to write CSS codes, CSS is really easy to learn and fun.

Good luck